# If $\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}\le 1$, prove that $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)\ge 125$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, tangent-line-method

> **QUESTION:** Let $a,b,c$  be positive real numbers such that
> $$\cfrac{1}{1+a}+\cfrac{1}{1+b}+\cfrac{1}{1+c}\le 1$$
> Prove that $$(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)\ge 125$$ When does equality hold?

---

**MY APPROACH:** Firstly, let's try to squeeze out all the information we can from what is given. $$\frac{(1+b)(1+c)+(1+a)(1+c)+(1+a)(1+b)}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}≤1$$ Multiplying this out, we get $$3+2(a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ca)≤1+(a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ca)+abc$$ $$\implies 2+(a+b+c)≤abc$$ Also, since $$1≥\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+a}$$ Therefore by AM-GM,

$$1≥\sum_{cyc}\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}}$$

$$\implies (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)≥27$$

That's all I ended up in.. At first, I thought Hölder's inequality could be employed, but that too requires the sum of the powers to be $=1$.. and that is not going to be useful in $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)$ , since here the sum of powers add up to $3$..

I don't know what to do next.. Any help will be much appreciated..

Comment: When $a=b=c=2$.

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Ccfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Ba%7D%2B%5Ccfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bb%7D%2B%5Ccfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bc%7D%5Cle%201%24&p=1) finds answers on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h616647p3673419, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1710367p11026034.

Comment: Rule of thumb.  Equality holds if $a=b=c$.  Which would mean $a=b=c = 2$  and ..... sure 'nuff.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $$abc\geq a+b+c+2\overset{AM-GM}{\geq} 4\sqrt[4]{2abc}\implies abc\geq 8$$Now,$$\prod_{cyc} (1+a^2)=\prod_{cyc} \left(1+\frac{a^2} 4+\frac{a^2} 4+\frac{a^2} 4+\frac{a^2} 4\right)\overset{AM-GM}{\geq}\prod_{cyc} 5\times \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{8/5}=125\times(abc/8)^{8/5}\geq 125$$

Answer (score 5):

Another way.

Since by AM-GM  $$\prod_{cyc}\frac{a}{1+a}=\prod_{cyc}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+a}\right)\geq\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\prod_{cyc}\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1+b)(1+c)}}=\frac{8}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1+a)},$$ we see that $$abc\geq8$$ and by  Holder we obtain:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+1)\geq\left(\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}+1\right)^3\geq(4+1)^3=125.$$

Comment: Generalized Hölder directly gives $$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)\geq\left((abc)^{\frac32}+1\right)^3.$$ I think that is more straight-forward.

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch Yes of course! :)  Thank you!

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch I think that will be $$\big((abc)^{\frac{2}{3}}+1\big)^3$$ and not $(abc)^\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @StrangerForever Definitely, it was a typo but I noticed it only after I was able to edit the comment. But Rozenberg got it correct anyway :)

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch My name is Michael. You can say also Michael Rozenberg.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ok thanks Michael 

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(\ln(a^2+1)-\ln5)\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\ln(a^2+1)-\ln5-\frac{36}{5}\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{a+1}\right)\right)\geq0,$$ which is true because for any $a>0$ easy to show that:
$$\ln(a^2+1)-\ln5-\frac{36}{5}\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{a+1}\right)\geq0.$$
Indeed, $$\left(\ln(a^2+1)-\ln5-\frac{36}{5}\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{a+1}\right)\right)'=\frac{2(a-2)(5a^2+2a+9)}{5(a^2+1)(a+1)^2},$$ which gives $a_{min}=2$ and we are done!

I got the coefficient $-\frac{36}{5}$ by the following way.

Let $f(x)=\ln(a^2+1)-\ln5+\lambda\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{a+1}\right).$

We know that $f(2)=0$ and we'll choose a value of $\lambda$ such that $2$ would be a double point,

for which we need $f'(2)=0,$ which gives $\lambda=-\frac{36}{5}.$

Comment: First, take a bow for converting this sum into logarithm!!.. but I did not understand, from where did you get $$\frac{36}{5}\big(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{a+1}\big)$$

Comment: @Stranger Forever I added something. See now.